# Problems getting Quartz Composition to interact with JavaScript in browser

Tags: javascript, safari, webkit, embed, quartz-graphics

I'm trying to embed a simple Quartz Composition into a webpage using the embed tag. According to Apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/QuartzComposer/qc_webkit/qc_webkit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001357-CH3) and the [API reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/QuartzComposer_PlugIn_ProgGuide/QCPluginReference/QCPluginReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004517-CH4-SW4), this should be a very simple task, but selecting the embedded object in JavaScript doesn't expose the API.

Here's my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Quartz Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <h1>Quartz Test</h1>
    <hr/>
    <div id="content">
        <embed type="application/x-quartzcomposer"
        src="lineTest.qtz"
        id="myComp"
        width="300px"
        height="150px"
        opaque="false"/>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's my js:

```
var composition;

$(document).ready(function() {
    composition = $('#myComposiiton');
});
```

With this simple setup I should be able to write something like...

```
composition.loaded() //should be true
```

or

```
composition.inputKeys() //should return Array
```

Instead all I get are errors in the debugger like, **TypeError: Result of expression 'composition.loaded' [undefined] is not a function**.

Has anybody been through this or have suggestion on how I might be able to debug it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the obvious composition[0].loaded()  ?

The jQuery $ function returns an array of DOM elements that match your selection, even if there is only one element that matches.